# Why is rendering the parent component and the child trying to enter the child component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Why is rendering the parent component and the child trying to enter the child component

```
"react-router-dom": "^6.0.1",
```

when I enter on the route:
`http://localhost:3000/dashboard`- the view work

`http://localhost:3000/dashboard/employee` - rendering dashboard and employee view (both views)

`http://localhost:3000/dashboard/accounting` - rendering dashboard and accounting view (both views)

Documentation:

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#nested-routes

#### index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

#### App.js

```
import AppRouter from "./routers/AppRouter";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <AppRouter />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

#### AppRouter.js

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "../components/template/Navbar";
import AccountingHomeView from "../components/views/accounting/AccountingHomeView";
import DashboardHomeView from "../components/views/dashboard/DashboardHomeView";
import EmployeeHomeView from "../components/views/employee/EmployeeHomeView";
import HomeView from "../components/views/public/HomeView";
import LoginView from "../components/views/public/LoginView";

const AppRouter = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomeView />} />
        <Route path="dashboard" element={<DashboardHomeView />}>
          <Route path="employee" element={<EmployeeHomeView />} />
          <Route path="accounting" element={<AccountingHomeView />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/login" element={<LoginView />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
};
export default AppRouter;
```

#### DashboardHomeView.js (with outlet)

```
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

const DashboardHomeView = function () {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>DashboardHomeView</h1>
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
};

export default DashboardHomeView;
```

#### component children Accounting

```
import React from "react";

const AccountingHomeView = function () {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1> Accountin</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
export default AccountingHomeView;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also initially found this a bit confusing, but with nested routes the "parent" route is considered more of a "layout" component in that it is always rendered when its `path` matches, and renders all its children routes into its  outlet.

```
const AppRouter = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomeView />} />
        <Route
          path="dashboard"
          element={<DashboardHomeView />} // <-- always matched/rendered at "/dashboard*"
        > 
          <Route
            path="employee"
            element={<EmployeeHomeView />} // <-- conditionally matched/rendered
          />
          <Route
            path="accounting"
            element={<AccountingHomeView />} // <-- conditionally matched/rendered
          />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/login" element={<LoginView />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
};

const DashboardHomeView = function () {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>DashboardHomeView</h1> // <-- always matched/rendered at "/dashboard*"
      <Outlet /> // <-- conditionally matched/rendered children
    </>
  );
};
```

[Nested-Routes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#nested-routes)

> You may have noticed when clicking the links that the layout in App
> disappears. **Repeating shared layouts is a pain in the neck. We've
> learned that most UI is a series of nested layouts that almost always
> map to segments of the URL so this idea is baked right in to React
> Router.**

I believe what you are expecting is what is called an [Index Route](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#index-routes). It is what would be rendered on a "/dashboard" route when it *isn't* a layout/wrapper container.

> Notice it has the `index` prop instead of a `path`. That's because the
> index route shares the path of the parent. That's the whole point--it
> doesn't have a path.
>
> Maybe you're still scratching your head. There are a few ways we try
> to answer the question "what is an index route?". Hopefully one of
> these sticks for you:
>
> - Index routes render in the parent routes outlet at the parent route's path.
> - Index routes match when a parent route matches but none of the other children match.
> - Index routes are the default child route for a parent route.
> - Index routes render when the user hasn't clicked one of the items in a navigation list yet.

```
const AppRouter = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomeView />} />
        <Route path="dashboard" element={<DashboardLayout />}>
          <Route path="employee" element={<EmployeeHomeView />} />
          <Route path="accounting" element={<AccountingHomeView />} />
          <Route index element={<DashboardHomeView />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/login" element={<LoginView />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
};

const DashboardLayout = function () {
  return (
    <div /* with any layout styling */>
      .... other common layout content
      <Outlet />
      .... more possible common page content
    </div>
  );
};

const DashboardHomeView = function () {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>DashboardHomeView</h1>
      .... dashboard specific content
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score -1):

How about using the `exact` prop for the parent Route. Like `<Route exact path="dashboard" element={<DashboardHomeView />}>`. This may solve the issue.

Comment: `exact` is no longer a `Route` component prop in v6.x. [Routes and Route](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#routes-and-route). Route components now have `caseSensitive`, `children`, `element`, `index`, and `path` as props.