# React router dom (6.0.1) child route not working properly

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm working with react-router-dom v6.0.1 and I'm trying to setup a simple tree structure composed.

The problem is when I link the path **/items** Router redirectos to Item component. But when i link **/items/3** it still redirecting to Items component.

Any tip?

Heres is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from '../screens/Home';
import Items from '../screens/Items';
import ItemsDetail from '../screens/ItemsDetail';
import NotFound from '../screens/NotFound';


export default function RouteConfig() {
  return (
     <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="items" element={<Items />}>
          <Route path=":itemId" element={<ItemsDetail />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
      </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

Comment: Please share the `Items` and `ItemsDetail` components code. As you've structured it `Items` is a layout component and needs to render an `Outlet` for its children/nested routes.

Comment: Items is a simple react component that returns <h1>Item</h1> and ItemsDetail another simple react component which returns <h1>Item Detail</h1>

Comment: Right, then `Items` needs to render an `Outlet` for the children routes. Would you like me to provide an example as an answer?

Comment: oh... then is not replacing the view. Okei.... i thought it has another behaviour. Thx mate

Comment: This post/answer may also help clarify for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69891698/why-is-rendering-the-parent-component-and-the-child-trying-to-enter-the-child-co/69892062#69892062

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should try separately
like this:

```
<Route path="/items" element={<Items />}>          
</Route>

<Route path="/items/:itemId" element={<ItemsDetail />} />
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, yes this way works but i want to use hierarchy and don't know why does not works :(

Answer (score 2):

With react-router-dom v6, we need to define the `<Outlet />` in the parent route, where we want the child routes to be rendered.

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#outlets

Comment: This should be an accepted answer.